# How to get edit text values from list view on button click

Tags: android, listview, android-edittext

I have two edit texts and text views in my list view.The text view values are set from Sq lite through adapter.and I have a button outside list view. My problem is when I clicks the button the values in each edit text will be stored to an array and later I can store it to the SQLite again. But I get null values when running the code. I tried so many methods from other questions but failed.Please help to get the answer.

Here is my code

```
    protected void InsertDb() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

     View v;
            HashMap<String, String> itemdata = new HashMap<String, String>();

            for (int i = 0; i < list.getChildCount(); i++) {
            v = list.getAdapter().getView(i, null, null);
            cases = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.cases);
            pcs = (EditText)v.findViewById(R.id.pcs);
             itemdata.put("cases", cases.getText().toString());
            itemdata.put("pieces", pcs.getText().toString());
                }
          Log.v("working correctly", itemdata.toString());
}
```

[this is how my activity looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HLsrM.png)
Thanks in advance..

Comment: This is not how you can read the views from an adapter. `getView` the way you are calling it only returns empty `EditText`. Can you elaborate more on what you want to achieve?

Comment: @  hoomi I just want to get values from edit text .this Edit text resides inside a list view.Since the size of the list view is large, Each time when I run the application it need not to enter values in all edit texts.Some may kept empty.I want the values which I entered in the edit text ,by iterating the list view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Activity:**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements   View.OnClickListener {
private ListView mList;
private Button mButton;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    mList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    mButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.click_btn);
    MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(this);
    mList.setAdapter(adapter);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });
    mButton.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if(mList != null){
        for(int i = 0; i< mList.getChildCount();i++){
            View vie = mList.getChildAt(i);
            EditText ed1= (EditText) vie.findViewById(R.id.edone);
            EditText ed2 = (EditText) vie.findViewById(R.id.edtwo);
            Log.d("value",ed1.getText().toString());
            Log.d("value",ed2.getText().toString());
        }
    }
}


class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    public MyAdapter(Context context){
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 5;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = convertView;
        if(row == null){
            row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_list,parent,false);
        }
        return row;
    }


   /* class MyViewHolder{
        public MyViewHolder(View v){

        }
    }*/

}
```

}

**activity_main:**

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary" app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />


    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end" android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**content_main.xml:**

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main" tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/list">

    </ListView>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Click Me"
        android:id="@+id/click_btn"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:layout_below="@+id/list"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**item_list.xml:**

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
>


    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/edone"
       />




    <EditText
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/edtwo"
        android:layout_below="@+id/edone"
        />



</RelativeLayout>
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.naveenbm.edittexttest" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: @ Naveen Shriyan  when I tried this I get the following stack trace.still I cannot get the values "03-11 12:23:31.419: V/working correctly(2917): {pieces=, cases=}"

Comment: r u sure that those pieces and cases are having values?

Comment: yes i enter values through edit text and when i click a button i want to take values from edit text and insert to sq lite. But i can't take values from it.Could you please check my updated question? I provide  my activity image there.

Comment: the above sample is working for me jus check with this n let me know.

Comment: This code helps me to get values from edit text.it retrieves null values also. Even though I got almost desired output..Thank you very much..

Comment: @Bivin : Happy to help You :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that getting a reference to the `EditText` is difficult from the `ListView`. I'm suggesting the following approach.

- Have 2 class variables of type `String Array`
- `String[] csArray = new String[];`
- `String[] pcsArray = new String[];`

Now on your list's Adapter's getView method, add a `TextWatcher` and populate the `csArray` and `pcsArray` whenever the user changes the value.
E.g.

```
@Override
```

`public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {`
    `csEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {`

```
    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        csArray[position] = s.toString();
    }
});`
```

// Repeat the same for `pcsEditText`

Now, on the button press method, simply get the value you require from the `csArray` and `pcsArray` objects.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing this line

```
 v = list.getAdapter().getView(i, null, null);
```

**With**

```
v = list.getChildAt(i);
```

Comment: It didn't retrieve values to the map. I get a null hash map when I tried to print it in log.